# Import hibernate into a project in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate

I work on a project already developped by someone else and I'm actually trying to run it. This project is using Hibernate but all the import are creating an error in Eclipse. I found that the project needs a .xml file where hibernate is configured but I don't know if it's the problem.

This is the import in the project :

```
import org.hibernate.Criteria;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.criterion.CriteriaSpecification;
```

And this is the .xml file :

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate     Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-    configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
    <property          name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>

    <property name="connection.datasource">java:persystDs</property>        
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>  
    <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
    <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">false</property>
    <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">false</property>
    <property name="show_sql">false</property>  
    <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>

    <property name="hibernate.transaction.factory_class">org.hibernate.transaction.CMTTransactionFactory</property>


    <property name="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class">org.hibernate.transaction.JBossTransactionManagerLookup</property>

</session-factory>
```

Help please !

**EDIT :**

This is the parts where hibernate is :

```
<exclusion>
                <groupId>eu.akka.jbossas</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>eu.akka.jbossas</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
<exclusion>
                <groupId>eu.akka.jbossas</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>eu.akka.jbossas</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            </exclusion>



<dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.1.GA</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
                <groupId>javassist</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>



<dependency>
        <groupId>fr.inra.grignon</groupId>
        <artifactId>persyst-common</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax</groupId>
                <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Do you use Maven or ANT to build your project ?

Comment: @GillesBodart No, I'm using JBoss and Tomcat.

Comment: classpath? have you checked it to include hibernate??

Comment: Humm I wasn't talking about your container :) 
Maven is used to manage the dependencies of your project and ANT is a building script. I recommand you to see a bit more about this.

Does the library been imported into the build path of your project ?

Comment: Reading the error message might be useful, don't you think? Why are you using JBoss AND Tomcat. They're redundant.

Comment: @JBNizet "The import org.hibernate cannot be resolved"

Comment: @JBNizet This is not MY project, I have to adapt myself to the technologies already employed. It's not my fault if they were using JBoss and Tomcat.

Comment: So, you don't have the Hibernate jar files in your build path, or you have them but need to clean your project to make Eclipse happy.

Comment: @GillesBodart How can I check it ?

Comment: @JBNizet do you have a pom.xml in the project ?

Comment: I'm not blaming you. I'm asking. Since they're redundant, you'd better know which one you actually use, though. I think you should ask "them" to brief you.

Comment: @GillesBodart Yes, I have.

Comment: perfect can you edit your post and put the content of the pom.xml ? (you are using Maven)

Comment: @JBNizet I'd like but it's an old project, and nobody knows.

Comment: @GillesBodart I edited

Comment: @JBNizet you have putted the overview, can you show me the pom.xml tab  (bottom)

Comment: @GillesBodart I'm not the OP. Ask Erlaunis, not me.

Comment: @JBNizet oups sorry :p

Comment: @Erlaunis you really need to take a step back, and learn the basics of Maven first.

Comment: @GillesBodart Sorry :/ I saw after edit the tabs.

Comment: @Erlaunis no problem, can you put the content ?

Comment: If you need hibernate, you must declare it as a dependency in your POM file.

Comment: @GillesBodart I edited

Comment: Have you tried building the project? The dependencies won't just magically appear.

Comment: @JamesB The dependencies seem to exist

Comment: Seem to? They obviously don't, otherwise eclipse would find the jars and you would not see errors like "the import cannot be resolved"

Answer (score 1):

You project seems to be not well imported,

can you import it again ?

[image: Import in eclipse]

after you select

[image: Maven project]

And you select your project

If you can't add you project, maybe change all the pom.xml with this

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>fr.inra.grignon</groupId>
<artifactId>fr.inra.grignon.hibernate</artifactId>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.1.GA</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
                <groupId>javassist</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>fr.inra.grignon</groupId>
        <artifactId>persyst-common</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax</groupId>
                <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
</dependencies> 
</project>
```

Comment: After alt+F5, I have nothing in the Available Maven Codebases list

Comment: @Erlaunis  It should :) right click on the pom.xml, do you have a Maven submenu ?

Comment: Yes :  "add dependencies, add plugin, new maven project module and select maven profiles "

Comment: I'm trying but it import without all the packages

Comment: It's because you have a bad pom.xml, did you putted all the pom or just only a little part ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92730/discussion-between-gilles-bodart-and-erlaunis).

Comment: Only a little part, the entire file is 425 lines